# Logging in users over Http in Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-webpages

I have a WebPages based WebMatrix website with Login and Registration enabled and I need to be able to Login using my Windows Forms application aswell.

I'd prefer to *not* use a Web Browser control, and instead, just create a Login Form control in my app with a Username and Password field, then send/POST the form to the https login page, but what I don't know what to do at this point is how to know if the user has successfully logged in?

How can I check on that from within a Windows Forms app?

Comment: What does it mean to log-in like this? are you going to be retrieving information back from said webservice, or do you just want to determine if the user is valid?

Comment: Information will be passed back and forth. It's a massive website, so I can't really re-write the site in a different way to make it more of a "web service".

Comment: So besides from validating the user, you will also use that winform to gather data (e.g. records) from your website? That's going to be a pain in the butt to parse those records from Html. If you only need to validate the user and assuming you are using Membership provider, you can use the Membership library on your WinForm. Just make sure you add the membership and roleManager from your web.config settings into your app.config.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in your situation is to parse output. For sure response contains "login failure" or something like this.

Second option is to add simple webservice to site.